# how do i make a string case insensitive in hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

In the below code i want to make "OrgLoginId" case insensitive. For example if OrgLoginId value is 'NSE' and in table org_loginid='Nse' then also I should get the result. Pls help me..

My Code:

```
public String getLoginId(String OrgLoginId) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside getLoginId method : start");
        List result=null;
        String loginId=null;
        try
        {
            org.hibernate.Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
            String SQL_QUERY = "select org_loginid from users where org_loginid='"+OrgLoginId+"'";
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY);
            result=query.list();
            loginId=(String)result.get(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return loginId;
    }
```

Comment: Depends on the database you're using, but likely: `where lower(org_loginid)='"+OrgLoginId.toLowerCase()+"'"`

Comment: I would recommend to lowercase the names of the tables and use the answer above